# iOS - What Objective-C Methods Do I Need To Make IBInspectable Work?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, ibinspectable

This is the following code I have for a custom `UIView` class I made where you can control it's shadows in the interface builder:

```
#import "ShadowView.h"

@interface ShadowView ()

@property (copy, nonatomic) IBInspectable UIColor *shadowColor;
@property (assign, nonatomic) IBInspectable CGFloat xOffset;
@property (assign, nonatomic) IBInspectable CGFloat yOffset;
@property (assign, nonatomic) IBInspectable float shadowOpacity;
@property (assign, nonatomic) IBInspectable CGFloat shadowRadius;
@property (assign, nonatomic) IBInspectable CGFloat xInset;
@property (assign, nonatomic) IBInspectable CGFloat yInset;

@end

@implementation ShadowView

#pragma mark - Lifecycle

//-(void)awakeFromNib {
//    [super awakeFromNib];
//    [self setUpView];
//}

-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [super drawRect:rect];
    [self setUpView];
}

#pragma mark - Helpers

-(void)setUpView {
    self.layer.shadowColor = _shadowColor.CGColor;
    self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(_xOffset, _yOffset);
    self.layer.shadowOpacity = _shadowOpacity;
    self.layer.shadowRadius = _shadowRadius;
    CGRect shadowRect = CGRectInset(self.bounds, _xInset, _yInset);
    self.layer.shadowPath = [[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:shadowRect] CGPath];
}

@end
```

When I use `awakeFromNib`, the shadows work on the iPhone 5 simulator but only half of them work on the iPhone6 emulator. `drawRect` seems to work for all, but I've seen Swift examples that use `init(frame: CGRect)` and `init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)`. What are the needed methods for me to get this right all the time?

Note: I'm not using `IB_DESIGNABLE` in this case since shadows don't render in the interface builder.

Comment: i'm not sure, but I think you can't use IBInspectable without setting the class to be IB_DESIGNABLE

Answer (score 0):

When you use IBInspectable, you didn't need add a -(void)setupview method to set all property. you must add separate setter method like below:
e.g.

```
-(void)setShadowColor:(UIColor)color {
     _shadowColor = color;
     self.layer.shadowColor = _shadowColor.CGColor;
}
........
```

hope it can help you.